# Difference between __pragma(deprecated) and __declspec(deprecated)

Tags: c, windows, pragma

To declare an object as deprecated in C/C++ under Visual Studio, you have three solutions:

- `#pragma deprecated(X)`
- `__pragma(deprecated(X))`
- `__declspec(deprecated(X))`

The first two ones are the same, except that only the second one can be used inside a macro; I've put the first one only for completeness. The third one seems to be the most used in the dev community.

I wonder what is the difference between the last two ones. According to the documentation on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8xdzzhh.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/044swk7y.aspx), I understand that there is no difference. What is strange in that case is that a different warning code is raised depending on what you're using: C4995 for the pragma-case, C4996 for the declspec-case.

So does somebody knows if there is actually a difference (any tiny one), or why these directives don't raise the same warning code?

Comment: The #pragma scales poorly on large projects since it is not attached to a specific function you want to deprecate.  Accidental matches are a risk, particularly in C++ namespaces.  No such problem with the __declspec, it should be your preference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [deprecated (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/044swk7y.aspx):

> (Microsoft specific) With the exceptions noted below, the **deprecated** declaration offers the same functionality as the deprecated pragma:
>
> - The **deprecated** declaration lets you specify particular forms of function overloads as deprecated, whereas the pragma form applies to all overloaded forms of a function name.
> - The **deprecated** declaration lets you specify a message that will display at compile time. The text of the message can be from a macro.
> - Macros can only be marked as **deprecated** with the deprecated pragma.

---

For `#pragma` vs. `__pragma`, see [Pragma Directives and the __Pragma Keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805.aspx):

> The __pragma() Keyword
>
> **Microsoft specific**
>
> The compiler also supports the **__pragma** keyword, which has the same functionality as the **#pragma** directive, but can be used inline in a macro definition.

---

It makes sense to note, as **@Deduplicator** mentioned, that **C++14** introduces the `[[deprecated]]` attribute.

> **7.6.5 Deprecated attribute [dcl.attr.deprecated]**
>
> The *attribute-token* `deprecated` can be used to mark names and entities whose use is still allowed, but is
>   discouraged for some reason. [ *Note*: in particular, `deprecated` is appropriate for names and entities that
>   are deemed obsolescent or unsafe. —*end note* ]

Comment: Yes, I just look at that point. Indeed, only the declspec solution allows a custom message during compilation.

Answer (score 4):

One more thing I just found out.

I have this class defined in a header file:

```
class X
{
   void F1();
   void F2();
}
```

Now, I want to deprecate F1, but when you use the `pragma deprecated` I get the warning every time the header file is included, even if F1 is never used.

```
class X
{
#pragma deprecated(F1)
   void F1();
   void F2();
}
```

Now change it to using the `__declspec(deprecated())` and you only get the deprecated message when and exactly where F1 is used. In my opinion you should never use `#pragma deprecated` unless you want people to use `#pragma warning (disable: 4995)` as it is pretty nasty to have warnings that you can't get rid of.

```
class X
{
   __declspec(deprecated("Please use F2")) void F1();
   void F2();
}
```

Comment: It matches the comment of Hans Passant; definitely, `__declspec(deprecated())` should be preferred in all cases except for deprecating a macro. Thank you for having pointed out this fact for C++.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `__declspec(deprecated)` doesn't work on `using` declarations, while `[[deprecated]]` does.

- Non-working: https://godbolt.org/z/lOwe1h
- Working: https://godbolt.org/z/1CEj66